# Java 6 on Linux - Shutdown hook not started by SIGTERM or SIGINT signal

Tags: java, signals, shutdown-hook

We recently updated our Java runtime environment from an old Sun/Oracle Java 6 version (1.6.0_18) to the most recent version, 1.6.0_45. Our application runs in the Java runtime without the -Xrs option. We are now seeing that our shutdown hook is not executed if the Java runtime process is sent a SIGTERM or SIGINT signal. But the shutdown hook is started if SIGHUP is sent.

This behavior seems to contradict the documented behavior for the Oracle Java runtime on Linux. Has anyone else seen this problem or have ideas to check for other changes in our Linux environment that may be causing the behavior we are observing?

Comment: I am having a similar experience except there has been no JRE update was working just fine with SIGTERM, suddenly not respecting and have no clue what has changed. I am using Java 7.